# Creating a scala project on intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

Trying to create a scala based project on intelli and all the tutorials i see ask me to click on new project and select scala on the left and sbt on the right.
I cannot see a scala option on the left.
[image: Screenshot of the new project window on intellij]

I have already installed the scala plugin. Also restarted intellij several times.

[image: Screenshot of plugin installed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project wizard in recent IntelliJ versions looks and works a bit differently than before. You need to select the primary language for the new project and then specify additional details such as SDK and build tool versions.

In your case, you need to choose Scala in the "Language" selector, then `sbt` in the "Build system" section (the options in the section change based on the language chosen):

[image: New Project Wizard]

For more information, consult the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/new-project-wizard.html).